# Error bundling vendor libraries with webpack

Tags: webpack

Trying to bundle all my main libraries into one file using webpack but with no luck
my webpack.config.js below

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main:  [
                './core/vendor/jquery.min.js',
                './core/vendor/bootstrap.min.js',
                "./core/vendor/knockout-3.3.0.js",
                "./core/vendor/knockout.mapping-latest.js",
                "./core/plugins/owl.carousel.min.js",
                "./core/vendor/jquery.mobile.min.js"
            ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/Public/build",
        filename: '[name]-bundle.js',
        publicPath: "/build/"
    }
}
```

However, when I run webpack I get

```
ERROR in ./core/vendor/knockout.mapping-latest.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'knockout' in /vagrant/webpack/core/vendor
 @ ./core/vendor/knockout.mapping-latest.js 1:93-112

ERROR in ./TapBet/Static/js/core/vendor/jquery.mobile.min.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jquery' in /vagrant/webpack/core/vendor
 @ ./core/vendor/jquery.mobile.min.js 3:55-111
```

Any ideas?

Thanks